# How to match a column from File1 to get its corresponding fasta sequences in File 2?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, command-line, bioinformatics

May I kindly ask how to match all values of the first column in File with the line text in File 2 so I can copy the fasta sequences of all Object ID in File 1?

File 1.csv file

```
Object_ID, Length, Assignment
NODE_142_length_92872_cov_11.2497,92872,2005469
NODE_405_length_50717_cov_10.7964,50717,82654
NODE_775_length_33402_cov_18.9306,33402,1147
NODE_1008_length_27630_cov_17.7829,27630,1184
```

File 2 fasta.file

```
>NODE_1_length_501653_cov_19.284
TGGTGTGAGAGGCGCACCTCGCTAACTTTTCAGTTAGCGAGGCCGTCTACTCGATTAGCT
GTTATGAGCCCGACGAGCTACCAACTGCTCCATCCCGCGATATTGTGATGCAAAGGTAAG
>NODE_142_length_92872_cov_11.2497
ATTAACTACTAAGTTACAAATTTTAGTAGCTGTCCAGTTTAAAGGAAGTATTTCATATTT
TCGCTTACGTTAAATAGGAAAAGCAAGTTCTTTTTTGAGGTACCCAGTGAGTCTGATTTT
```

OUTPUT FILE

```
>NODE_142_length_92872_cov_11.2497
ATTAACTACTAAGTTACAAATTTTAGTAGCTGTCCAGTTTAAAGGAAGTATTTCATATTT
TCGCTTACGTTAAATAGGAAAAGCAAGTTCTTTTTTGAGGTACCCAGTGAGTCTGATTTT
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via :

```
for i in `awk -F ',' '{print $1}' file1.csv `; do grep $i fasta.file ; done
```

Here I am first extracting `Object_ID` from file1.csv using, 
`awk -F ',' '{print $1}' file1.csv`

and then running a loop around it to extract from other file

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. But I have this error now>> samtools/1.3.1 has been loaded.
faidx: invalid option -- 'c'

Usage:   samtools faidx <file.fa|file.fa.gz> [<reg> [...]]

Comment: I did exactly the steps you enumerated. And this is my slurm:

Comment: module load samtools
#samtools faidx B1_scaffolds.fasta
#awk -F, 'NR > 1 { print $1 }' <B1clark_cyano.csv >regions.txt
samtools faidx -c B1_scaffolds.fasta.fai -r regions.txt >B1clark.fasta                           Then my error is:                                                                                                         >> samtools/1.3.1 has been loaded.
faidx: invalid option -- 'c'

Usage:   samtools faidx <file.fa|file.fa.gz> [<reg> [...]]

Comment: I cannot produce my fasta file for the targeted sequences

Comment: for i in `awk -F ',' '{print $1}' file1.csv `; do grep $i fasta.file ; done   This did not work but gave me the same file as my .csv

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Fasta file is called `fasta.fa` and that the CSV file is called `sequences.csv`, and that you have [SAMtools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMtools) (a fairly standard bioinformatics package) installed.

1. Index the Fasta file:

   ```
   samtools faidx fasta.fa
   ```
2. Extract the names that you want to extract into `regions.txt`:

   ```
   awk -F, 'NR > 1 { print $1 }' <sequences.csv >regions.txt
   ```

   This file has the format `region:start-stop` (one per line) where `region` is a sequence name and `start` and `stop` denotes the region within that sequence that you'd like to extract.  I'm assuming that you want to extract the complete sequence, so I don't put `start` or `stop` in there.

   If you want to use the numbers in the CSV file as `start` and `stop`:

   ```
   awk -F, 'NR > 1 { printf("%s:%d-%d\n", $1, $2, $3) }' <sequences.csv >regions.txt
   ```
3. Extract the sequences into `output.fa`:

   ```
   samtools faidx -c fasta.fa -r regions.txt >output.fa
   ```

Sequence names in `regions.txt` that can't be found in the Fasta file would be outputted as empty sequences in `output.fa` (and `samtools` would warn about these too).

See also:

- The StackExchange [Bioinformatics site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I did exactly the steps you enumerated. And this is my slurm:                                                                                                         module load samtools                                                                               #samtools faidx B1_scaffolds.fasta                                                                  #awk -F, 'NR > 1 { print $1 }' <B1clark_cyano.csv >regions.txt                    #samtools faidx -c B1_scaffolds.fasta.fai -r regions.txt >B1clark.fasta

Comment: Then my error is:                                                                                                   >> samtools/1.3.1 has been loaded. faidx: invalid option -- 'c' Usage: samtools faidx <file.fa|file.fa.gz> [<reg> [...]]

Comment: I still don't have yet my fasta file

Comment: @beth See if you have a module that provides version 1.9 of Samtools (this is what I use). Does `module load samtools/1.9` work? Check with other users of your system what versions of Samtools is available.

Comment: samtools/1.3.1 is the one currently installed in our system